How can I copy all event stream data from an endpoint in Chrome DevTools?
Is there a workaround or a method within Chrome DevTools that allows for copying all the event stream data of an endpoint at once? If not directly possible through DevTools, is there any alternative approach or tool that can achieve this?
What I’ve tried:

Right-clicking on individual messages to use the “Copy message” option, which is not sufficient for my needs.

Any suggestions or insights into capturing complete SSE data more efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

You can try doing it in devtools-on-devtools by inspecting its internal data.

You can try to right click on the event stream in the network tab and "Copy Response", that worked for me.
Chrome Devtools
